# How can you count the number of occurrences of all of the words in a text area using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had a textarea and a user pasted a paragraph into the textarea, can statistics be run on the input using JavaScript on the client side? I was thinking of using an associative array or hash map so array[word] -> # of occurrences, and iterate through word by word but I'm not sure how to do this using client side JavaScript.

I tried searching JavaScript word count but I only get results on counting the total number of words, which is not what I'm looking for. What I am looking for is more keeping a count of each specific word. Can this be done in Javascript or Jquery? If so, how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach for you

```
// first get an array of words
var words = text.split(' ');

// use Array.prototype.reduce (for example) to
// create statistics
var statistics = words.reduce(function (stat, word) {
    if (!stat[word]) stat[word] = 0;
    stat[word]++;
    return stat;
}, {});
```

**UPDATE**: A little example which handles punctuation and upper/lower case, too: http://jsfiddle.net/1pnLzv8h/1/

Comment: You need too to handle cases for `word,`, `word.`, `word!`, etc...

Comment: Yea, you should also handle lower/upper case, numbers, etc. But I thought I leave it as an exercise for the OP

Comment: Ya, that's a good starter for sure

Comment: One way this reader might handle that exercise (:smile:) is `var words = text..replace(/\W*(?:\s|^|$)+\W*/g, ' ').split(" "); ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var arra = ['ab','pq','mn','ab','mn','ab']

function wordCount(arra,val)
{
    var ob={};
    var len=arra.length;
    for(var k=0;k<len;k++)
    {
        if(ob.hasOwnProperty(arra[k]))
        {
            ob[arra[k]]++;
            continue;
        }
        ob[arra[k]]=1;
    }
    return ob[val];
}

alert(wordCount(arra,'ab')); //output 3
```